# Text under Add to cart (woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

How can I add a text saying "Contact us for bulk purchase enquiry" under 'Add to cart' button for all woocommerce products.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding this code to your functions.php  file :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'content_after_addtocart_button_func' );

function content_after_addtocart_button_func() {
// Echo content.
echo '<div  style="font-size:10px;"><em>(*Contact us for bulk purchase enquiry)</em></div>';
}
```

Hope it helps!