# Add custom text below Add To Cart button in WooCommerce single product pages

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, product

So I have attached an image of my issue.

[image: The code is right up on the button]

Basically I followed the instructions on this Stack Overflow question thread right here: 
[Text under Add to cart (woocommerce)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44059449/text-under-add-to-cart-woocommerce/46590997#46590997)

I posted my question there 5 times and someone kept removing it, so I'm posting it again here.  Please advise.

Update: I have already tried the paragraph tag, the break tag, and the pre tag.

Comment: Help others to help you.

Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Edit your post, and show the code that you are working on.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this (as you will see this is a CSS styling issue with the `margin-top`):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'custom_content_after_addtocart_button', 100 );
function custom_content_after_addtocart_button() {
    // custom content.
    echo '<br/><div><p style="font-size:10px; font-style=italic; margin-top:20px;">(*Contact us for bulk purchase enquiry)</p></div>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme or in any plugin file).

Tested and works. You will get that:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This code will place it nicely below the Add to Cart button :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form','content_after_addtocart', 100 );
  function content_after_addtocart() {
  // place your content below.
  echo 'Hello There !!';

   }
```